# How does the C++ compiler dynamically replace namespace during compilation?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I am new to C++ and trying to understand how the preprocessing, compilation and linking steps are working. I stumbled across an interesting behaviour while I was trying to use [`gflgas` library](https://github.com/gflags) library.

### Code

The following is the code that I am using for my example here:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <gflags/gflags.h>

DEFINE_string(name, "Tugberk", "Name of the person to greet");

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gflags::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, true);
    std::cout << "Hello " << FLAGS_name << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see I am using `gflags::` to reach out to `ParseCommandLineFlags` function. I am assuming that `gflags` here is the namespace (but I am pretty sure I am wrong here, more on that later).

### Compilation

I have ran the following commands to compile this code:

> The reason that I am calling `cc1plus` is to mimic the `g++` step to create the `.s` file so that I can eventually use that to create the `.o` file through the assembler. I don't have intention to directly invoke `cc1plus`.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE main.cpp -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase main -version -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -o /tmp/ccFyWgz8.s
```

Then, I used the `as` command to produce an `.o` file so that I can inspect it using `nm`, llvm symbol table dumper.

```
as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccONcT86.o /tmp/ccFyWgz8.s
```

### What I Have Observed

I then used `nm` on the `.o` file I was able to produce and at that point I observed that the namespace for the `ParseCommandLineFlags` function is changed to `google`:

```
# nm -C /tmp/ccONcT86.o
0000000000000000 V DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
00000000000001a0 t _GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN3fLS10FLAGS_nameB5cxx11E
                 U _Unwind_Resume
000000000000006f t __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
0000000000000000 B fLS::FLAGS_name[abi:cxx11]
0000000000000000 W fLS::StringFlagDestructor::StringFlagDestructor(void*, void*)
0000000000000000 W fLS::StringFlagDestructor::StringFlagDestructor(void*, void*)
0000000000000000 n fLS::StringFlagDestructor::StringFlagDestructor(void*, void*)
0000000000000000 W fLS::StringFlagDestructor::~StringFlagDestructor()
0000000000000000 W fLS::StringFlagDestructor::~StringFlagDestructor()
0000000000000000 n fLS::StringFlagDestructor::~StringFlagDestructor()
0000000000000000 W fLS::dont_pass0toDEFINE_string[abi:cxx11](char*, char const*)
0000000000000060 b fLS::FLAGS_noname
0000000000000070 b fLS::d_name
0000000000000068 b fLS::o_name
0000000000000020 b fLS::s_name
                 U google::FlagRegisterer::FlagRegisterer<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)
                 U google::ParseCommandLineFlags(int*, char***, bool)
                 U std::allocator<char>::allocator()
                 U std::allocator<char>::~allocator()
                 U std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))
                 U std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)
                 U std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
                 U std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()
                 U std::ios_base::Init::Init()
                 U std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
                 U std::cout
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
0000000000000000 r std::piecewise_construct
0000000000000008 b std::__ioinit
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
0000000000000000 W operator delete(void*, void*)
0000000000000000 W operator new(unsigned long, void*)
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 U __dso_handle
                 U __gxx_personality_v0
                 U __stack_chk_fail
0000000000000000 T main
```

After checking the `gflags` source code, I can see in the following two places where this might have come from:

- https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/827c769e5fc98e0f2a34c47cef953cc6328abced/src/gflags.h.in#L97
- https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/827c769e5fc98e0f2a34c47cef953cc6328abced/src/gflags_declare.h.in#L41-L43

When I checked the installed version of the `gflags_declare.h` file, I can see the namespace being defined as `google`.

```cpp
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Namespace of gflags library symbols.
#define GFLAGS_NAMESPACE google
```

### Question

I assumed `gflags` in context of `gflags::ParseCommandLineFlags` statement was the namespace, but it doesn't seem to be. Where did this come from and why the compiler was happy with this? How did the compiler know to replace `gflags::` with `google::` at the first place?

Comment: That's what the `#define` preprocessor directive does - something like macro substitution.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm that makes sense but I am not sure how the compile knew to replace `gflags::` part in my code with that at the first place. Another way to ask this is how the compiler knew what I was referring to by stating `gflags::`? Is it because the header file is called `gflags.h `?

Comment: @Ron I cannot figure out from that document how `gflags` is resolved through in my example here. Would you be able to point me to the specific phrasing for that?

Comment: @Ron That makes super sense to me. What I am struggling is that `GFLAGS_NAMESPACE ` is not used in my code at all, it's used inside the library header files. So, I cannot understand how `gflags::` reference in my code is being interpreted as "replace that with 'google'".

Comment: `#ifdef gflags` then `#error OMG gflags is a define!` then `#endif`

Comment: Another possibility is a namespace alias, as in `namespace gflags=google;` or perhaps more subtly `namespace gflags=GFLAGS_NAMESPACE;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik not exactly but this made me found it! It seems like it was trying to support the old namespace, see https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/827c769e5fc98e0f2a34c47cef953cc6328abced/src/gflags.h.in#L623, https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/5d5a6c550100fa9d19f18861b61be9343e94dbcb/CMakeLists.txt#L350-L357.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Igor's comment above, I was able to find that this was happening due to `gflags` namespace also being exported for backwards compatibility. See https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/827c769e5fc98e0f2a34c47cef953cc6328abced/src/gflags.h.in#L623 and https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/5d5a6c550100fa9d19f18861b61be9343e94dbcb/CMakeLists.txt#L350-L357

On the installation, this created the following entry within the `gflags.h` file:

```
// Import gflags library symbols into alternative/deprecated namespace(s)
#include "gflags_gflags.h"
```

Generated content of the `gflags_gflags.h` file is as following:

```cpp
#ifndef GFLAGS_GFLAGS_H_
#  error The internal header gflags_gflags.h may only be included by gflags.h
#endif

#ifndef GFLAGS_NS_GFLAGS_H_
#define GFLAGS_NS_GFLAGS_H_


namespace gflags {


using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::int32;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::uint32;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::int64;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::uint64;

using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::RegisterFlagValidator;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::CommandLineFlagInfo;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::GetAllFlags;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::ShowUsageWithFlags;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::ShowUsageWithFlagsRestrict;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::DescribeOneFlag;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::SetArgv;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::GetArgvs;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::GetArgv;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::GetArgv0;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::GetArgvSum;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::ProgramInvocationName;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::ProgramInvocationShortName;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::ProgramUsage;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::VersionString;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::GetCommandLineOption;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::GetCommandLineFlagInfo;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::GetCommandLineFlagInfoOrDie;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::FlagSettingMode;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::SET_FLAGS_VALUE;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::SET_FLAG_IF_DEFAULT;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::SET_FLAGS_DEFAULT;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::SetCommandLineOption;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::SetCommandLineOptionWithMode;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::FlagSaver;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::CommandlineFlagsIntoString;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::ReadFlagsFromString;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::AppendFlagsIntoFile;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::ReadFromFlagsFile;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::BoolFromEnv;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::Int32FromEnv;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::Uint32FromEnv;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::Int64FromEnv;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::Uint64FromEnv;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::DoubleFromEnv;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::StringFromEnv;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::SetUsageMessage;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::SetVersionString;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::ParseCommandLineNonHelpFlags;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::HandleCommandLineHelpFlags;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::AllowCommandLineReparsing;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::ReparseCommandLineNonHelpFlags;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::ShutDownCommandLineFlags;
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::FlagRegisterer;

#ifndef SWIG
using GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::ParseCommandLineFlags;
#endif


} // namespace gflags


#endif  // GFLAGS_NS_GFLAGS_H_
```